# GetConstructors doesn't find the declared constructor

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm experimenting with `System.Type`. In the following code, I used `GetConstructors` on an array type:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Animal 
{
    public Animal (string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Type AnimalArrayType = typeof(Animal).MakeArrayType();
        Console.WriteLine(AnimalArrayType.GetConstructors()[0]);
    }
}
```

The output is: `Void .ctor(Int32)`. Why? Shouldn't it be `Void .ctor(System.string)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called `.MakeArrayType()` so you're doing reflection on an array of `Animal`, not `Animal` itself.  If you remove that, you'll get the constructor you expected.

```
Type AnimalArrayType = typeof(Animal);
Console.WriteLine(AnimalArrayType.GetConstructors()[0]);
```

If you wanted to get the element type of an array type, you can do it like this.

```
Type AnimalArrayType = typeof(Animal[]);
Console.WriteLine(AnimalArrayType.GetElementType().GetConstructors()[0]);
```

In order to construct an array of the desired size, you can use this.

```
Type AnimalArrayType = typeof(Animal[]);
var ctor = AnimalArrayType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
object[] parameters = { 3 };
var animals = (Animal[])ctor.Invoke(parameters);
```

Comment: Where does `Void .ctor(Int32)` come from, though?

Comment: You're seeing  the constructor for the array type.  There is one that takes an integer.

Comment: Thanks. And a related one: If i'd like to use the returned constructor to instantiate an `Animal[]` of, say, 3 elements, how should I do that? I tried the following (obviously) failed attempt: `Type AnimalArrayType = typeof(Animal[]); Type[] passed_params = new Type[1] { typeof(string) }; ConstructorInfo ci = AnimalArrayType.GetElementType().GetConstructors()[0];  Animal[] animal_arr = (Animal[])ci.Invoke(new object[] { "monkey" });`

Comment: Thanks. However, is it possible to not only define a place for 3 Animal elements (so there are 3 null Animal references), but also instantiate those 3 elements by calling `Invoke`?  The current solution separates the array space allocation and the invocation of each Animal element constructor (not in your answer, but need to be done, of course) to 2 separate steps. I wonder if this can be done together.